# Verify SHA256 signature of received message

Tags: .net-core, cryptography, azure-functions

I need to verify a SHA256 signature where we receive in every communication the message, signature and public key.

I'm trying to load a public key we receive in an Azure Function (.net core 3.1) into a X509Certificate2 object to be able to verify the signature of a received message and signature.

The following code is used:

```csharp
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();        
var data =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestObject>(requestBody);
var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data.key);
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(keyBytes);
```

When the last statement fires, the following exception comes up:

```
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(Byte[] rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[] data)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData)
   at leo_signing_library.Function1.<Run>d__0.MoveNext() in 
C:\Users\Leo\source\repos\leo-signing-library\Function1.cs:line 30
```

When running in debug the following error comes up in the debug window:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
CheckSignature.  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates: Geen
overeenkomend object gevonden.
```

Just for clarity a screenshot of the debug window:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRiH8.jpg)

I've added the nuget package `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` (version 4.3.2), but no effect.

Does anyone know how to overcome this? Or has a working example of verifying a signature based on a public key not stored in the certificate store?

**Edit 1:**
I'm trying to load the following public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1iyta8F+SLHhbfy+f7fL
8LrsS1LKs05UaHm6muOTlzIdSDwo4dNiWg6rbiL2v4IwpglgL8kvbXLZ8Z3/E6Uu
uUi/IW1Hakgx65Qy4LkGxsnZ/jnLu3DxfY9xycMYq9TfNxIIvFPkbEJY/pwGjZ+q
13WegTJG7m+tqf5GbA3xTLz2DSHXPc7y77OnsDawHsOEou9IZZQCdxCg3L186gU4
yj6mC07Eop3lKMjsqNAXdVmnzcUc+PixQFCSjOcL9Fpbq+aHyYW+Pk9h5dWCGGNQ
wixTIJKTeDxAEkbZ2eLuqQZOCNbkHBn9x+IBxeKMmsmRg/J4/QqwCm+t+wd4VNAJ
ewIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you kindly share the entire stack trace?

Comment: Seems like `data.key` is not a certificate. Based on the name it’s probably a public key, not a cert.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I've updated the question to make more clear what I want to do

Comment: This is a public key in SPKI or X509 format, PEM encoded. Under .NET Core 3.1 there is [`RSA.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=netcore-3.1), for importing such a key, but DER encoded. To convert PEM to DER, remove header and footer and Base64 decode the body.